# Placing text inside a loop

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I add the same text that appear inside the area surrounded by the arrow above the phrase "Item-based", meaning, `{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$}` but inside the area surrounded by the arrow next to the text "User-based similarity measure"?

> **CODE**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,b/.style={text=blue,font=\bfseries}]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    column 5/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column 6/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    row 4/.style={nodes={fill=orange!30}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ 
        |[fill=none]|\dots & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ 
        $u_{j}$ & 3 &  & |[b]| ? &  & |[b]| ? & 3 & &  0 \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        \dots& & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\
    };
    \draw[-latex](m-6-9.east)--+(1,0)node[above right]{User-based similarity measure}|-(m-5-9.east);
    \node[left]at(m-4-1.west){Active User};
    \draw[latex-] (m-1-6) -- ++ (-1,1) node[above left,align=left]
    {Item preference score is\\ predicted for active user};
    \draw[-latex]([xshift=-2pt]m-8-6.south east)--++(0,-1) -| 
    ([xshift=2pt]m-8-5.south west)
    node[pos=0.25,below]{Item-based}
    node[pos=0.25,above,font=\tiny]{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the loop is built with the syntax `|-`, it is sufficient to use the specific placement of nodes on such paths. To know:

- 0.5 is the right angle
- .25 is half of the first segment.

For aesthetic reasons, I have divided the text into two lines.

```
\draw[-latex,align=center](m-6-9.east)--+(1.8,0)node[above right]{User-based\\ similarity measure}|-(m-5-9.east)node[pos=.25,left]{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,b/.style={text=blue,font=\bfseries}]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    column 5/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column 6/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    row 4/.style={nodes={fill=orange!30}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ 
        |[fill=none]|\dots & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ 
        $u_{j}$ & 3 &  & |[b]| ? &  & |[b]| ? & 3 & &  0 \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        \dots& & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\
    };
    \draw[-latex,align=center](m-6-9.east)--+(1.8,0)node[above right]{User-based\\ similarity measure}|-(m-5-9.east)node[pos=.25,left]{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
    \node[left]at(m-4-1.west){Active User};
    \draw[latex-] (m-1-6) -- ++ (-1,1) node[above left,align=left]
    {Item preference score is\\ predicted for active user};
    \draw[-latex]([xshift=-2pt]m-8-6.south east)--++(0,-1) -| 
    ([xshift=2pt]m-8-5.south west)
    node[pos=0.25,below]{Item-based}
    node[pos=0.25,above,font=\tiny]{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is more or less repetition from the answer that yielded your code. It is designed in such a way that, if you add more text, the arrow loop will adjust its size.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,b/.style={text=blue,font=\bfseries}]
    \matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,
    nodes={minimum size=5ex,anchor=center,draw},
    row 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    column 5/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    column 6/.style={nodes={fill=gray!30}},
    row 4/.style={nodes={fill=orange!30}},
    column 1/.style={nodes={draw=none,fill=none}},
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep={-\pgflinewidth},
    nodes in empty cells,
    ]{
        & $i_{1}$& $i_{2}$ & $i_{3}$ & \dots &$ i_{k}$    & $ i_{a}$  & \dots &$ i_{n}$ \\ 
        $u_{1}$ & & 5 &   & 2 & 4    &    &  &  \\ 
        $u_{2}$ & & 5 & 4 &  & 5 &   & 4  &\\ 
        |[fill=none]|\dots & &   &   &  &   & 1 & 1 & 2   \\ 
        $u_{j}$ & 3 &  & |[b]| ? &  & |[b]| ? & 3 & &  0 \\ 
        $u_{a}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        \dots& & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\ 
        $u_{6}$ & & |[b]| ? & 2 &  & 4 &  &|[b]| ? &  \\
    };
    \node[left]at(m-4-1.west){Active User};
    \path (m-6-9.south east) -- (m-5-9.north east) 
     node[midway,right,font=\tiny] (ub) {$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
    \draw[-latex](m-6-9.east) --
    ([xshift=2pt]ub.east|-m-6-9.east) |-(m-5-9.east)
    node[pos=0.25,right,align=left]  {User-based si-\\milarity measure};
    ;
    \draw[latex-] (m-1-6.north) -- ++ (-1,1) node[above left,align=left]
    {Item preference score is\\ predicted for active user};
    \draw[-latex]([xshift=-2pt]m-8-6.south east)--++(0,-1) -| 
    ([xshift=2pt]m-8-5.south west)
    node[pos=0.25,below]{Item-based}
    node[pos=0.25,above,font=\tiny]{$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To see this automatic adjustment, try

```
\path (m-6-9.south east) -- (m-5-9.north east) 
 node[midway,right] (ub) {$\mathrm{sim}(u_{a},u_{j})$};
```

to get

[image]

There is no hardcoded distance.